# C program using SDL2 only sometimes draws Rect

Tags: c, sdl, sdl-2

When I call the following functions:

```
SDL_SetRenderDrawColor(rend, 0, 0, 0, 255);
SDL_RenderClear(rend);
SDL_SetRenderDrawColor(rend, 100, 255, 80, 255);
SDL_RenderFillRect(rend, &canv);
SDL_RenderDrawRect(rend, &canv);
SDL_RenderPresent(rend);
SDL_Delay(6000);
```

it only ***sometimes*** draws the rectangle, at other times at keeps whatever was at the window location before, or draws the window entirely black. The above functions all return 0.

rend and canv are defined as follows:

```
Uint32 rend_flags = SDL_RENDERER_ACCELERATED | SDL_RENDERER_PRESENTVSYNC;
SDL_Renderer * rend = SDL_CreateRenderer(win, -1, rend_flags);
      
SDL_Rect canv;
canv.x = 0;
canv.y = 0;
canv.h = 640;
canv.w = 480;
```

And this is the makefile used:

```
CC=gcc
CFLAGS=-lSDL2

spectra: spectra.c
    $(CC) -o spectra spectra.c $(CFLAGS)
```

So where did I go wrong, what am I overlooking?

Comment: Try drawing it continuously in the main loop.

Comment: That does work, but is it intended that one has to draw continuously? Is it not faulty behaviour when a single iteration does nothing?

Comment: @wintermute It's not faulty behaviour, you decide how things are drawn on screen. If you clear your screen every frame, then yes it has to be redrawn every frame. But it's not mandatory.

Comment: Yes, at least for games it's normal. I've not tried it, but think the alternative is to listen for `SDL_WINDOWEVENT_EXPOSED` and redraw everything when it tells you (in addition to redrawing when you actually want to).